# Solve pythagoras theorem in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ide

I am working on a programm which lets you calculate the sides in a triangle using the Pythagoras method. I recently posted my first question about this. How can I code it so that you can also work out B or A. Here is my code so far:

**PythagorasCalc.m**

```
  #import "PythagorasCalc.h"

  @implementation PythagorasCalc

 - (double)calculatePythagorasValue {
   return sqrt(A*A+B*B);
 }

//Access Code

- (double)A {
   return A;
}

- (void)setA: (double)value {
    if(A != value) {
       A = value;
    }
}

- (double)B {
  return B;
}

- (void)setB: (double)value {
   if(B != value) {
       B = value;
    }
}

- (double)C {
    return C;
}

- (void)setC: (double)value {
   if(C != value) {
       C = value;
    }
 }

@end
```

**PythagorasCalc.h**

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface PythagorasCalc : NSObject {
    @private
    int A;
    int B;
    int C;
}

@property (nonatomic) double A;
@property (nonatomic) double B;
@property (nonatomic) double C;

- (double)calculatePythagorasValue;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "PythagorasCalculatorAppDelegate.h"

@implementation PythagorasCalculatorAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    calculator = [[PythagorasCalc alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)calculateClicked:(id)sender {

    double A = _ATextField.doubleValue;
    double B = _BTextField.doubleValue;
    double C = _CTextField.doubleValue;

    calculator.A = A;
    calculator.B = B;
    calculator.C = C;

    _CTextField.doubleValue = [calculator calculatePythagorasValue];  
}
@end
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "PythagorasCalc.h"

@interface PythagorasCalculatorAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    //Public Calculator Object
    PythagorasCalc *calculator;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)calculateClicked:(id)sender;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *ATextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *BTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *CTextField;

@end
```

Comment: As a first step, you could fix the indenting and remove excessive empty lines to make it better readable for you and us :-)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Some people doesn't post any code, and you post everything you've got.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem: `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`, that means `a^2 = c^2 - b^2` or `a = sqrt(c^2 - b^2)`, similarly `b = sqrt(c^2 - a^2)`. Of course you must check the quantity inside square root is positive, otherwise it's not a valid right-angled triangle.

Comment: @TimothyGroote no, its not

Comment: @MartinR the indents are only here on the website, its hard to post code here

Comment: @TimothyGroote but I'm still in school - and too lazy to work harder pythagoras equations out in my head

Comment: @code i don't care if bill gates himself once said a good developer is a lazy developer, but with that kind of attitude, how are you ever going to learn?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen also pretty much sorted your maths problem out for you. it's not that hard anymore.

Comment: @TimothyGroote you are right. But thats not exactly what I meant. I can solve the equations but I have a reason for doing this stuff. It is a thing about my teacher. He tells everyone to work it out in excel so I told him that I could make a programm and he said that I could.

Comment: Then what's stopping you?

Comment: @TimothyGroote I worked out most of my code now but it gives me weird answers when I calculate something

Comment: I agree with @KhanhNguyen . I would create three methods, one for calculating B based on A and C, one for calculating C based on A and B, and one for calculating A based on B and C.